# Absurdly large /proc/kcore file -- what does it mean?

Tags: backup, proc

I had to abort a backup of my system because it stalled on the file `/proc/kcore`. I check its size and, well, the file is enormous. Checking Google, it seems that many other people have absurdly large kcore files as well.

I have three questions:

1. should I be concerned about kcore's size?
2. if so, how can I reduce its size?
3. is there any reason to backup the /proc/ directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First things first: **[`/proc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/proc.5.html) is a virtual filesystem**. Do not back it up. Its contents do not exist on the disk.

From `man 5 proc`:

```
/proc/kcore
      This  file  represents  the physical memory of the system and is
      stored in the ELF core file format.  With this pseudo-file,  and
      an unstripped kernel (/usr/src/linux/vmlinux) binary, GDB can be
      used to examine the current state of any kernel data structures.

      The total length of the file is  the  size  of  physical  memory
      (RAM) plus 4KB.
```

So, I'd be a bit concerned if the `kcore` is small.

How do you reduce its size? Reduce your RAM.

Comment: But my kcore file is 140.7 ___TERRABYTES___ big with 4 GB RAM ?

Comment: My guess that it is address space.  Mine in 128T which is the size mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080778/2184122